# Create UICollectionView class and add into Storyboard

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, storyboard

Subclass `UICollectionView` and trying to set in Storyboard VC.

```
class CategoryCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, ReusableView, NibLoadableView {
  
  /// Local
  var categoryDataSource: CategoryDataSource!
  
  typealias CategoryDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CommunityType>
  typealias CategorySnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CommunityType>
  
  override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
    configure()
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  fileprivate func configure() {
    self.register(CardTypeCell.self)
    self.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()
    self.delegate = self
  }
  
  private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    let padding: CGFloat = 5
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 152, height: 70)
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    return flowLayout
  }
}
```

Getting an error on `init` method:
**'self' used in property access 'collectionViewLayout' before 'super.init' call**

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, because we're missing a lot of your code (`Section`, `CommunityType`, etc), but...

This line:

```
super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
```

Should be:

```
super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```